# How do I choose web hosting?

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I have a couple of personal web-based projects in the pipeline, and am unable to chose how to host them.

I have questions in the area of domain names and actual file hosting (which I believe are separate topics, though many companies provide both).

### Domain Names

I have a domain name registered with Freeparking.co.uk, but they don't offer the kinds of services I think I need.  Can I just transfer the domain name to somewhere else?  Apart from anything the only thing they do is to host a page with a full-page frame on it, which I configure a URL for.  Basic URL hiding, but that means that people can't bookmark specific pages in my websites.

### Hosting

I wish to host ASP.NET applications (plural) using SQL Server 2005.  What are the steps to choosing a hosting environment, and how do I connect the domain name to the hosting environment?

Comment: Take a look at related questions to see how many times this has been asked.

Comment: Oh really?  Sorry, I did look at the suggested related questions when I wrote the subject in the "ask question" form, and didn't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain names are best kept separate from the hosting. Decent domain registrars let you freely define *name severs*, which in then give the IP address for the domain. Typically (but not necessarily) these name servers are provided by the hosting company. So, the steps are:

1. Choose the hosting provider (sorry, I have don't recommendations on ASP hosting providers).
2. Configure the name servers so that at least the A record of yourdomain.com points to the ip of your server (this is often automatically done by the hosting company).
3. Configure your domain name at the registrar so that it refers to the the above mentioned name servers.

Also the domain name registrar can provide the name server stuff, or you can use for example [EveryDNS](http://www.everydns.com/).

Comment: Ah, point 2 in your answer is possibly the link in the chain that I was missing - many thanks.  Sooo obvious, too.  Oh well. :)

Answer (score 1):

your domain name is just an IP address in their Name Server which drives Domain Name System - DNS.  Check that Freeparking actually do NameServer stuff.

1. You can choose what ever host that meets your requirements.
2. your host will have there own DNS system (ie the IP address of the server that will be your web application host).
3. Ask Freeparking to point your Domain Name the name at the new IP.

I needed the same ASP.Net and SQL and went for DiscountASP.net (although they are in the US), excellent service so far =>

They also do the email side too.  The MX part of your domain name.

Comment: When I used them some years ago, FreeParking gave you complete access to the nameservers, so you could set up your A, CNAME, Mail, etc records without any bother.